# React Hook useCallback has an unnecessary dependency: 'price'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {Fragment, useState,useCallback } from "react";

const ProcessingSearch = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState({ maxPrice: 0, minPrice: 0 });

  const inputMaxMin = useCallback(
    ({ target: { value, name } }) => {
      name === "maxPrice"
        ? setPrice(({ minPrice }) => ({ maxPrice: value, minPrice }))
        : setPrice(({ maxPrice }) => ({ minPrice: value, maxPrice }));
    },
    [price]
  );

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={() => {}}>
        {"Min"}
        <input
          {...ProcessingSearchInputPrice}
          value={price.minPrice}
          onChange={inputMaxMin}
        />
        {"Max"}
        <input
          {...ProcessingSearchInputPrice}
          value={price.maxPrice}
          onChange={inputMaxMin}
        />
        <input type="submit" title={"Submit price range"} value={"Go"} />
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

When I use price I get an error:

> React Hook useCallback has an unnecessary dependency: 'price'. Either exclude 
>   it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a warning for `useCallback` implementation (not because of `price` usage).

As the warning states, remove `price` variable from the dependencies array `[price]`:

```js
const inputMaxMin = useCallback(
    ({ target: { value, name } }) => {
      name === "maxPrice"
        ? setPrice(({ minPrice }) => ({ maxPrice: value, minPrice }))
        : setPrice(({ maxPrice }) => ({ minPrice: value, maxPrice }));
    },
   []                 // <--- remove price, not used within the hook.
  );
```

In this case, I believe you can remove the use of `useCallback` because you don't memoize anything, check the example.

[image: Edit Check-If-Render]

Comment: `setPrice` shouldn't be needed as a dependency.

Comment: Yea you right, in this case, no need for callback right?

Comment: `useCallback` without dependencies (`[]`) should work

Comment: It will work, but there is no reason for `useCallback` for this case, what exactly it memoize?

Comment: I think It prevents `<input>` fron rerendering ... Although that is just a very slight improvement though.

Comment: Why doesn't the same apply to the `useEffect` hook? `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` doesn't warn me about `valueWhichMayChange` being unneeded in the following example (line 13) -> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-ey9pw?file=/index.js

Answer (score -1):

I can't figure out why `screens` are not needed as dependency and why I have to remove them.

[image: Edit dazzling-kapitsa-d0i9d]